# How to fire an event when a slide change

Tags: jquery

I am integrating a flexslider into a site. http://flexslider.woothemes.com/index.html

Now, I wish to add a class before and after to the current slide. Every time when the current slide changes, the classes will be updated. I managed to do it with the following jquery:

```
  setInterval(checkCurrent, 100);

  function checkCurrent(){
    $('.gallery #slider li').removeClass('beforeCurrent afterCurrent');

    var current = $('.gallery #slider li.flex-active-slide');

    current.prev().addClass('beforeCurrent');
    current.next().addClass('afterCurrent');
  }
```

However, this way it will run the function every 100 milliseconds which I think less sensible. I don't intend to use any function flexslider provides as I need to apply the same to other slider plugin in the future. I need purely a jquery solution. Any suggestion ?

Comment: read all property/options of flexslider here https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties

you can ise `befor` or `after` option as per your requirement

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I wish to add a class before and after to the current slide?

Instead of using `setTimeout` use callback function of `Flexslider`:

> There is already **before** and **after** callabck function [**Details**](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties)

```
$('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    start: function(){},// Fires when the slider loads the first slide
    before: function(){},// Fires asynchronously with each slider animation
    after: function(){},// Fires after each slider animation completes
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `before:`  and `after:` attribute to perform this task just like this

```
before: function()
{

$('.gallery #slider li').removeClass('beforeCurrent afterCurrent');
}
```

and add class with

```
after: function()
{
var current = $('.gallery #slider li.flex-active-slide');
current.prev().addClass('beforeCurrent');
current.next().addClass('afterCurrent');
}
```